# Using different Auth mock up in Spring Junit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm using Spring and Junit4 to tests my server application. My application uses Spring Security and some queries take advantage of SpEL syntax to check the logged user.

Because I'm testing some scenarios that needs some data loaded I've some issues because I've not right to do that.

For example:

```
@Test
    @WithUserDetails(userDetailsServiceBeanName = "mockUserDetailService", value = "customer")
    public void saveEcommerceTicket() {
        ZonedDateTime entryDate = ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
        createStandardFare();
        createDailyCode(entryDate.toInstant());
        createPaymentWithWallet();
        Customer customer = createCustomerWithWallet(new BigDecimal(100));

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setLicensePlate1("AA123BB");
        ticket.setArea(areaCentroStorico);
        ticket.setDailyCode("CC");
        ticket.setEntryDate(entryDate.toInstant());
        ticket.setExitDate(entryDate.plusDays(1).toInstant());
        ticket.setPassengers(50);
        ticket.setPassengersCountry(italy);
        ticket.setCustomer(customer);

        ticket = ticketService.saveFromEcommerceWithWalletPayment(ticket, new ArrayList<Media>());

        assertEquals(true, ticket.isStandard());
        assertEquals(TicketStatus.VALID, ticket.getStatus());
        assertTrue(new BigDecimal(100).compareTo(ticketRepository.sumPayments(ticket.getId())) == 0);
        assertTrue(BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(customer.getWallet().getBalance()) == 0);
        assertEquals(true, ticket.isPaid());
    }
```

This is an example of test where I use a custom userdetailservice. Unfortunately some actions like: createStandardFare(), createDailyCode(), etc, requires a different role.
I tried to set up manually authentication but I end up always to have the entire test with one ROLE. Instead I need that some parts are executed with a specific ROLE (let's say ADMIN) and some others with another (let's say CUSTOMER).

Is there a way to accomplish this with Spring and Junit?

Comment: for check roles you can use `@WithMockUser(roles = { "ADMIN", "CUSTOMER" })` for example.

Comment: @borino I need to check part of the code with a specific role (ADMIN) and the other part with another role (CUSTOMER). Is that possible?

Comment: in this case you need separate the test. Or declare two roles, as on example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are invoking different methods within a single test method that require different roles, you only really have two options.

1. Configure a mock user (e.g., via `@WithMockUser` or similar) that is assigned all of the roles used within the test method.
2. Switch the current mock user programmatically within the test method itself.

   - For example, using the following code snippets.

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    login("customer", "password", "ROLE_CUSTOMER");
    // ...
    login("admin", "password", "ROLE_ADMIN");
    // ...
}

static void login(String username, String password, String... roles) {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

    User user = new User(username, password, roles(roles));

    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, user.getAuthorities());
    context.setAuthentication(auth);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
}

static List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roles(String... roles) {
    return Arrays.stream(roles).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
}
```

Note: `User` in the above example is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`.

Comment: I had to use two different user roles in the same test method, this code did the job! thanks :-)